# X100 Rainbow glare on artificial light

Tags: fujifilm, lens-flare, glare, fujifilm-x100

I've been experiencing this issue on my Fujifilm x100, every artificial light has a strange blue / rainbow glare. It is the first time I notice something like this and I'm pretty sure it doesn't happen with my other camera (X-T4).

I know the x100 is a pretty old one, but is there a way to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does it change when the ND filter is moved in and out?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the lens is greasy. Probably some condensation on the lens.

If it is condensation, it could be on the interior of the lens. See if there is a lot of humidity, or if your camera has moved from cold to hot or vice versa.

One way to fix condensation is to leave the camera in a warm dry place for a couple of hours. Do not leave it under direct sunlight.

Comment: I might add it may even be hard to notice because not a lot of dirt is required to have this when lights are so bright.

Comment: Often people will attempt to clean fingerprints off a lens' surface with a dry cloth. "Cleaning" the exterior of the lens with a dry microfiber cloth won't help. All one does is spread the oily substance evenly over the surface of the lens. One needs to use a few drops of lens cleaning fluid on a *clean* section of the cloth to clean the surface, then use a *clean* dry section of the cloth to dry it.